# Capped Collection with JDO

Tags: mongodb, jdo

I'm just starting out with MongoDB and JDO (DataNucleus.)

I'm trying to figure out how to use Capped Collections in JDO, any pointers? Am I missing some kind of annotation on an object, or is it more complex than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is coming in DataNucleus 3.1.2: http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/jira/browse/NUCMONGODB-104